# How to install and run a Fuji Xerox M225 dw on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, printing, xerox

I can see the printer, but it will only print blank pages. The default drivers do not work. Other answers on Ask Ubuntu do not have the answer. The system is a single 14.04 ubuntu on 64 architecture. The downloadable file from Fuji is useless and lacking the PPD file required. Running on a virtual is not an option as that would entail moving all printing back and forth. I just want to print direct. At this stage will be returning the printer as who doesn't provide linux connectivity out of the box?

Answer (score 4):

This is a year old question, but this is how I installed the printer and scanner drivers on Ubuntu 18.04:

This printer is the same as Brother DCP-L2540DW but unlike Fuji Xerox, Brother provides Linux drivers. First, go to http://support.brother.com/, search for DCP-L2540DW and download the following drivers for Linux (deb):

- LPR printer driver (deb package)
- CUPSwrapper printer driver (deb package)
- Scanner driver 64bit (deb package)

Then install them (in above order) using the following command:

```
dpkg -i --force-all <filename>
```

**Network Printer Configuration**

- Go to Settings > Devices > Printers and click `Additional Printer Settings`.
- Click `+ Add` and expand `Network Printer`. You should see your printer (FX DocuPrint M225 dw) there after a few seconds.
- Click printer name and change the `Host` value to the IP address of your printer. Click `Forward`.
- It will automatically start searching for a suitable driver and fail. Select `Select printer from a database`, select `Brother` in the list and click `Forward`.
- Select `DCP-L2540DW for CUPS` and click `Forward`
- Rename the printer if you like and click `Apply`.

**Network Scanner Configuration**

- Open a terminal and type in the following command:

  `brsaneconfig4 -a name=M225dw model=DCP-L2540DW ip=<IP address>`

Comment: exact link to the device support page on Brother: https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=dcpl2540dw_us_as&os=128

Comment: YOU DID IT. I CAN PRINT ACROSS THE NETWORK NOW. YOU MADE PRINTING GOOD AGAIN.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 17 I got this working via Add Printer, then drop down the Network Printer and select the Fuji Printer. Then when the PPD dialog appears I selected

Generic PCL 6/PCL XL Printer - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.11

Alternatively if you've already added the printer you can edit properties and select Change button next to "Make and Model".

Comment: Wanted CM225 (i.e. colour version) to work on 19.10 and this was the most helpful answer I found.  The above driver gave me working monochrome, so I at least knew it worked.  The FX Printer Driver for Linux gave me colour.  Hopefully this saves someone faffing time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link can help you: http://thebigbyte.blogspot.be/2013/07/linux-printer-drivers-fuji-xerox.html.  It states that these printers are not officially supported by Linux but shows a workaround, that I quote here for further reference :

1. First, download the Windows PostScript Printer Drivers from the Fuji website: http://www.fujixeroxprinters.com.au/en/Downloads.aspx?product=11252&category=5726&dl=1
2. Extract the zip file to a local directory.
3. Find the folder which matches your architecture - x64 for 64-bit machines, or x32 for 32-bit machines
4. Inside this folder you'll find a .cab file. Open this with your favourite archiver (I used Ark), and extract the contents.
5. One of the extracted files is called "fxtpn1a.ppd". This is the PPD file you'll need to install the driver on Linux.
   NOTE: You may need to run dos2unix over this file, to convert from Windows to Unix line endings. I also had to correct one line which was supposed to begin with an asterisk, but had a single space preceding it at the start of the line.
6. Under Ubuntu settings, open Printers, and click "Add".
7. Find the network printer, and connect using AppSocket/HP JetDirect.
8. When asked for a driver, choose "Local Driver", and "Provide PPD file".
9. Browse to the PPD file extracted earlier, and click through the rest of the wizard to finish adding the printer.
10. Print a test page to verify the drivers are working properly.

Comment: Cannot locate the "fxtpn1a.ppd" file. There are multiple .cab files and have trawled through them all.  Can use the software to connect to the printer but it will not print properly. The quoted article has dead links in it too, which is unfortunate. Thanks for the help, going to return the printer and add Fuji Xerox to my Do Not Buy list. Pretty angry with it, mainly at buying a printer without checking connectivity first.

Comment: Update: Found the file, amended it as per the instructions above, and it still prints one blank page for a 19 page document. Returning the printer and resisting the urge to do something nasty to Fuji Xerox. Will find a Ubuntu friendly printer first, and then buy it... Stupid me for not doing that first. Thanks again for the assistance. Each of these hurdles gets me better at Ubuntu though!